# does append() always extend minimal capacity needed?

Tags: go

When learning slice, I have this doubt: does append() always extend minimal capacity needed?

```
a := make([]byte, 0)
a = append(a, 1, 2, 3)
cap(a) == 3  // will this be always true?
// or the assumption may not hold since the underlying implementation of append()
// is not specified.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed in this case. The [specifications](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) say:

```
append(s S, x ...T) S  // T is the element type of S
```

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values, append allocates a new, **sufficiently large** slice that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Thus, the returned slice may refer to a different underlying array.

(Emphasizes mine)

In your case, clearly any capacity >= 3 is *sufficiently large*, so you *can rely* on `cap >= 3`, but *you cannot* rely on `cap == 3`.

Of course you can assume cap in this case will not be, say 1e6 or 1e9 or 1e12. However, the exact enlarging (allocating new backing array) strategy is intentionally not specified in every detail to allow the compiler guys to experiment with some knobs attached to this mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I would add that, not only does it *not guarantee* that the capacity of the slice would be equal to the length, in fact, for large lengths, it would *almost never* be the case where the resulting slice would have capacity would equal the length.

`append()` is promoted as the replacement to the `vector` package. In order to do this, the complexity of appending must match the complexity in the `vector` package, which means that appending an element must have amortized O(1) complexity. Although this complexity is not guaranteed in the language specification, it must be true for the patterns for which `append()` is used now in the Go community to work efficiently.

In order for `append()` to be amortized O(1), it must expand the capacity by a fixed percentage of the current capacity each time it runs out of space. For example, doubling in capacity. Think about it, if it doubles in capacity every time it runs out, the length and capacity can only be the same if the length is exactly a power of 2 (assuming it started out as a power of 2), which is not frequent.