# How the slice is enlarged by append? Is the capacity always doubled?

Tags: go

When `append` a slice, the slice may be enlarged if necessary. Because the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) doesn't specify the algorithm, I am curious about it.

I try to find the `append` implementation in the Go source code, but can't find it.

Could anyone explain the specified algorithm for enlarging slice? Is the capacity always doubled? or Could anyone provide the source code position of `append`? I can check it myself.

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15702419/720999) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17901497/720999).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[The code responsible for growing slices in `append` can be found here.](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/87e48c5afdcf5e01bb2b7f51b7643e8901f4b7f9/src/runtime/slice.go#L100-L112) (commit date: Oct 26, 2016)

As of 2014-2020 the implemented rules are:

1. If appending to the slice will increase its length by more than double, the new capacity is set to the new length.
2. Otherwise, double the capacity if the current length is less than 1024, or by 25% if it is larger.  Repeat this step until the new capacity fits the desired length.

Presumably this isn't part of the specification so the heuristics can be changed in future if needed. You can check the most current version of this implementation on the [master branch](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L144-L163).

Comment: Thanks for your answer firstly! If possible, could you explain a bit detailedly how the append call the growslice? I could't find this flow in the slice.c.

Comment: The compiler converts the `append` call to an appropriate `runtime.growslice` call followed by assigning the new values to the end of the slice.  You can see this in the assembly output from e.g. `go tool 8g -S filename.go`

Answer (score 8):

In Go 1.18 it changed.

- https://github.com/golang/go/commit/2dda92ff6f9f07eeb110ecbf0fc2d7a0ddd27f9d
- commit date: Sep 27, 2021

Commit message memo:

```
    starting cap    growth factor
    256             2.0
    512             1.63
    1024            1.44
    2048            1.35
    4096            1.30
```

Comment: That's interesting, and I guess that depending on the use case it can make total sense for a Go programmer to create his own algorithm when necessary.